# Autolayout Constraints Priority is not Resolving

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

I have a view which has a **UILabel**, a **UITableView**(`tblFilters`) and a **UIView**(`btnBaseView`)(to keep three other UIButtons).Please check the image below: -
[image]

I need to expand the `tblFilters` height to showcase the options for each category but need to have the `btnBaseView` always visible on the screen. So basically `tblFilters` height should not increase beyond a limit.

To achieve this i have applied a height constaint to `btnBaseView` and gave it **Required** priority. Same way `tblFilters` has a height constraint but a **DefaultHigh** priority.

```
// Height Constraint of btnBaseView. Height Should always be >=116
  btnSectionHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[btnBaseView(>=116)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"btnBaseView":btnBaseView}];
  [[btnSectionHeightConstraint firstObject] setPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired];
  [self addConstraints:btnSectionHeightConstraint];


// TableView Height Constraint. Height value is being changed when user click on "+" button of table section.
  tableHeightConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[tblFilters(>=%f)]",176.0] options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"tblFilters":tblFilters}];
  [[tableHeightConstraints firstObject] setPriority:UILayoutPriorityDefaultLow];
  [self addConstraints:tableHeightConstraints];
```

But this scheme doesn't seems to work as tableView is covering the entire baseView and pushed the `btnBaseView` out of visible area.

I have tried by keeping DefaultLow priority to `tblFilters` as well but no effect. When i debug the code after changing the `tblFilters` height constraint it print correct priority output in console but no effect over the view.

Can someone please help me in identifying the issue why constraint priority is not working as expected or do i have wrong understanding of this concept. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. set `tblFilters` height constraint priority to be
   `UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh`
2. set `btnBaseView` top margin constraint related by `tblFilters` to
   `0`
3. set `btnBaseView` bottom margin constraint related by `bottomView`
   to be `>= 0`

---

and then you change height constraint of `tblFilters` corresponding to the data

```
tableHeightConstraints.constant = someValue
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was applying the first 2 constraint already, now i have added the 3rd as well. Still it is not working.

Comment: I'm wondering. Is it 2 constraints in the question? because my suggested constraint are not the same as yours.

Comment: Not really, i have applied many other constraints related to each controls alignment and spacing. In question i have mentioned only the relevant ones.